# Hidden Object But Still Have a Place Reserved

Tags: javascript, html, css, visible

I'm trying to make two forms that aren't displayed at the same time. The first one stays visible when the page opens, but if the user select, the first one should be hidden and the second one might take it's place. So here is my CSS for this:

```
#switcher {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#web_upload {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#local_upload {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="img_upload.php" id="local_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="graphics/upload.png" />
    </center>
</form>
<form action="url_upload.php" id="web_upload" method="post" method="post">
    <center>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="graphics/upload.png" />
    </center>
</form>
```

And here is my Javascript to do it:

```
function showHide(id, other)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id)) {
        if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility != "hidden") {
            document.getElementById(other).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById(other).style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    } 
}
```

So, I'm having three problems:

- The second form has a reserved place on the page and I don't want this empty place
- The second form is displaying on that reserved place instead of taking place over the first one
- If the user select one of the options and try to select other after nothing happens

How I can solve this problems?

Comment: have you tried `display = "none"`?

Comment: Searching for the element every time you want to do soemthing is not good. Make a reference: `var element = document.getElementById(id); element.style.vidibilit = "hidden";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nathan Campos: I'd combine `display` and `visibility` like so --

**CSS:**

```
#web_upload {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#local_upload {
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showHide(id, other)
{
    var id1 = document.getElementById(id);
    var id2 = document.getElementById(other);

    if (id1.style.display == "none") {
        id1.style.display    = "inline";
        id1.style.visibility = "visible";

        id2.style.display    = "none";
        id2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if (id1.style.display == "" || id1.style.display == "inline") {
        id1.style.display    = "none";
        id1.style.visibility = "hidden";

        id2.style.display    = "inline";
        id2.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working great, but when the page opens, the space for the second form is there. After I click on the option, the space gets hidden and never appears anymore(what I wanted, but without the space before the user selects the option). Also the user can select another option after :)

Comment: The only problem now is that when the page loads the space is there

Comment: @Nathan Campos: The stylesheet might be cached, but perhaps adding the styles inline for now will do the trick, e.g. `<form action="url_upload.php" id="web_upload" method="post" method="post" style="display: none; visibility: hidden">`

Answer (score 4):

`display: none/block;` Show the form / Totally hide and clear the space

`visibility: hidden`; Hide the form, but keep the space preserved

Comment: I've tryed `display: none`, but now it won't get hidden, only if the `visibility: hidden` is on the CSS, and it still keeps the space reserved **:/**

Comment: Please make sure, that `diplay: none` is really applied to the right elements.

Just `alert()` both properties for both elememts.

Comment: `alert(id + ": " + document.getElementById(id).style.visibility + ", " + document.getElementById(id).style.display + "\n" + other + " : " + document.getElementById(other).style.visibility + ", " + document.getElementById(other).style.display);`

Answer (score 3):

The CSS `visibility` property is not the right choice here.

> The 'visibility' property specifies whether the boxes generated by an element are rendered. Invisible boxes still affect layout (set the 'display' property to 'none' to suppress box generation altogether)

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility

Consider instead the CSS `display` property - `display:none` applied to an element will make it appear as if it is not present at all, it will be invisible and will not affect layout.

```
#switcher {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#web_upload {
    display:none;
}

#local_upload {
    display:block;
}
```

//

```
function showHide(id, other)
{
    switch (document.getElementById(id).style.display) {
        case 'block':
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(other).style.display = 'block';

        case 'none':
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(other).style.display = 'none';            
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one won't get hidden now